# Android - Detecting nearby devices

Tags: android, geolocation, wifi-direct

I'm looking for a way to create the following:

When two or more android devices running my app are near each other they should both get a notification of this event.

I looked into some different ways to do this and thought of using a remote server to which all the apps frequently send their location, which would be quite battery / data heavy.

My other option would be to use WiFi direct / P2p, but I'm not very familiar with this technology, so I have a few questions about it:

1. I've googled it a bit and found different ranges, what is the approx. range of Wifi p2p?
2. Since my app involves a game of reaction speed it would be great to have the notification sent asap and simultaneously to each when the devices "bump" into each other. So my question is: how fast will nearby devices be able to connect to each other? (a message might also be sent to a remote server, which would then broadcast a notification)

I wasn't sure which StackExchange site to use, but I figured this one.

Any other suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Look at this page:
https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview
The maximum range is 30 meters.